# Must call buildParser before calling getParser

Tags: php, reactjs, smartcontracts

I am learning ACCORD project, while practicing i am facing the error https://docs.accordproject.org/docs/tutorial-studio.html

Below is the link to view the code. I am trying to change from clause to contract in the metadata. But not working out can some one please help me
'''https://studio.accordproject.org/?template=ap%3A%2F%2Fminilatedeliveryandpenalty-capped%400.6.0%23hash'''